# How do I add a required field using mongoose and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have an existing Schema:

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    field1: {type: String, required; true},
})
```

but I want to add another field, `field2` of type `Boolean`, to this schema and make it required. I also want all existing documents to have the `field2` value set to `false`. How would one go about doing this using a node server and mongoose?

I'm thinking that I might be able to have a prestart script that sets all existing documents' `field2` to false and that way all the existing documents will have the field, and any new documents would be required to have a `field2` set while saving because the schema will have been updated when the server starts. Is there a standard practice for this kind of stuff?

I am not asking how to create a default field in a mongoose schema. I was asking how to ensure that previous documents have a default and required field and how people normally go about populating previous documents in a collection. Please do not mark as duplicate.

@Fanpark, none of these questions answer my question. Please remove them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    field1: {type: String, required: true},
    field2: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: true
    }
})
```

this will add field2 to false at the creation of the object with .save, but will not modify the old documents. In the other hand, the method .find will add the field if it is not there and set it to false (just in query’s result, that will not update the document)

Comment: Oh really? It will do that in the query result? Is that how people normally go about 'adding a column' in mongodb? Just depend on the ORM to backfill?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have strong shema structure like all noSQL database so it is ok to do that.

Comment: Is this standard practice?

Comment: This is just how mongoose works

Comment: I get that! But the question is, is this standard practice for those who use mongoose? I.e. is this a common practice that happens in the real world within the confines of the way mongoose works? I'm sure there are other people do that do different things :)

Comment: For that I don't know, I have not use it in a enterprise context